# Working with more than one xml file in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android development.

If I have more than one xml file, other than the main.xml, then how can I call the other files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call it by name of the file. For examole for main.xml you call it as R.layout.main, so for my_menu_activity.xml it would be R.layout.my_menu_activity

Answer (score 1):

create new activity. (add new .java). then in main.java call
`Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NEW_ACTIVITY.class);

        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);`

and on start of onCreate OF NEW_ACTIVITY add

```
 this.setContentView(R.layout.NEW_XML);
```

in manifest.xml you must also add

```
<activity android:name=".NEW_ACTIVITY"></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either call the different xml files when needed, like so:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.yourname.xml);
```

If you need to load the contents of one xml, and put it in a view, then you can use an `inflater` to fetch a view from an xml that isn't 'loaded'. There is also an `addContentView()` command, but I don't think you'll need that for now :)